# Add a tooltip in this script . in any line?

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

How do I Add Tooltip in this script? I want that every line have a different tooltip description.
here the code of the time script that I use.

```
<strong class="GeneratedText">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<p>");
    var day = new Date();
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var d = weekday[day.getDay()];
    var hr = day.getHours();
    
    if (hr == 1 && d == "Sunday") {
        document.write("Nu: Nachtlijn");
    } else if (hr == 2 && d == "Sunday") {
        document.write("Nu: Nachtlijn");
    } else if (hr == 3 && d == "Sunday") {
        document.write("Nu :Nachtlijn");
    } else if (hr == 4 && d == "Sunday") {
        document.write("Nachtexpress"); 
    } else if (hr == 5 && d == "Sunday") {
        document.write("Nachtexpress");
    }
```

Comment: Add the `title` attribute to the `<p>` tag with the value being the tooltip text you want to display.

Comment: Thanks je for answering. But than I have te same tooltip output in all the lines.  It needs a different description by every line .

Comment: You can restructure your code so that you generate the `<p>` element differently  each time, e.g. place writing of `<p>` under each `if/else if`